# MulticastMessage with different badge number for every user

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set in my server side application the FCM service and I have been sending notifications (one by one) and has worked as expected.

Now, I'm trying to send notifications using MulticastMessage. It works good, devices are receiving notifications properly. However I don't know how to set a different badge number for every user. 
I'm using the `addAllTokens` method to set the devices, and I was looking something like `addAllBadges` to send a list of badges corresponding to every device I insert in `addAllTokens`, but I can not find a solution. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing something like.....
First of all you need to query your DB to get the device token and badge count respectively

So say like you have and array

```
const badgeCounts = [{
    device_token:'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    badge_count: 1
},{
    device_token:'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
    badge_count: 2
},{
    device_token:'cccccccccccccccccccccc',
    badge_count: 3
},{
    device_token:'dddddddddddddddddddddd',
    badge_count: 4
}]
```

`Now you can map over this array and compose array of fcm messages, something like below :-`

```
const fcmMessages = [];

badgeCounts.forEach((data) => {
  fcmMessages.push({
    token: data.device_token, //device token
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          alert: {
            title: "your title",
            body: "your body",
          },
          badge: data.badge_count, // badge
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
      },
    },
    data: {
      // any payload goes here...
    },
    notification: {
      title: "your title",
      body: "your body",
    },
  });
});

/// in firebase messiging you can do like
messaging.sendAll(fcmMessages);
```

refer doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging-1#sendall

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the message to each user in a multicast message is exactly the same. So if you need to show a different badge count, you'll need to do separate messages for these. But all recipients with the same content/badge count could be part of the same multicast message.

Comment: You can easily do this with .sendAll([.......message objects]) 
here send all thakes message object's as an array

Comment: Interesting and something I didn't know. I you can write up a small example of how to do that, and link to the relevant documentaiton, I'd recommend posting it as an alternative answer - so people can upvote and be more likely to find it.

Comment: Okay i did posted small write up script!!